# Переменная с идентификатором другой переменной python

Tags: python, telebot

Только начинаю в python, последний раз программировал на basic и он был совсем не visual. Поэтому терминологии - ноль.

telebot, бот для телеграм, проиходит сообщение от user_id. мне нужно создать переменную именно для этого юзера.

То есть например у меня есть набор признаков для каждого юзера и мне нужно его менять в зависимости от приходящих мессаг. например на текст "ушел" или "пришел" мне нужно измеить переменную **state** однозначно привязанную именно к идентификатору юзера, как то так :

**state**.message.from_user.id = 'home'

**state**.message.from_user.id = 'gone'

ума не приложу, в какую сторону копать, потому что я динозавр. Знаю про exec, но видимо это не лучший выход.
Понимаю, что вопрос совсем нубский и нужно погуглить, но видимо я не могу корректно сформулировать запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать словари, то есть сопоставлять значение и ключ, где ключом будет id:

```
state = dict()

state[message.from_user.id] = 'Пришел'
print(state.get(message.from_user.id)) # Пришел
```